# Only show a tab/page only for an IP

Tags: html

Hello so basically I want to make an hidden page/tab that will only show for a specific IP

```html
<ul class="right" id="menu">
  <li>
    <a class="selected" href="#msg">TEST</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You'll need some server-side language to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some PHP for this.

```
<?php 
// The <ul> is only showed for this IP adress
if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]=='0.0.0.0'){ ?>
    <ul class="right" id="menu">
      <li>
          <a class="selected" href="#msg">TEST</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well, thank you for that answer :) but how can I make like only IP from France can see the tabe/page?

Comment: You have to use either a geolocation API based on the IP address or a IP database. But *be careful*, users can use a proxy / VPN.